# Get a User's Authorities Based on the Current Request URI

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to have the ability to grant different authorities to users depending on which resource they're attempting to access. Of course, I could do this by implementing logic in each of the relevant controllers, but I would really like to take advantage of the Thymeleaf security extras in my templates, as well as Spring's `@PreAuthorize()` annotations.

As of right now I am using a simple implementation of a `UserDetails` to provide a list of granted authorities from some models in a database:

```java
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return this.userAccount.getRoles().stream()
            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

However, I want behavior that can do the following:

> User requests `/courses/1`. They're a student in that course, so they get these roles: (...)
>
> User requests `/courses/2`. They're an admin in that course, so they get these roles: (...)

The problem is that Spring's `UserDetailService` and `UserDetails` interfaces don't allow for auto-wiring the context's current request anywhere, as far as I can see. Is there any way that this can be done? Ideally I'd just want access to the `HttpServletRequest`. Something like this:

```java
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(HttpServetRequest request) {
    return this.userAccount.getRolesForURI(request.getURI()).stream()
            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: The authorities should be mapped based on the user credentials rather than the resource it's trying to access. The request to the resource can be manipulated, so an authenticated `student` can just make the request to the `admin` resource and get its authorities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply @Autowire the HttpServletRequest into your UserDetailsService.

```
 @Autowired
 private HttpServletRequest request;
```

For it to work you might need to register a RequestContextListener.

```
@Bean 
public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
    return new RequestContextListener();
}
```